# Apple Command Line Tool: Force Universal Binary with a Single Arch?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, command-line

I'm porting a C/C++ library using the library's makefile. The library includes a test suite and I'm having some trouble getting the EXE to work as expected when only using a single architecture. Below is a sample produced by the makefile's recipe (formatting added for readability):

```
$ export IOS_PLATFORM=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
$ make static dynamic cryptest.exe
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g -Os -pipe -fPIC -arch armv7
  --sysroot $(IOS_PLATFORM)/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
  -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM=1 -c 3way.cpp
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g -Os -pipe -fPIC -arch armv7
  --sysroot $(IOS_PLATFORM)/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
  -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM=1 -c adler32.cpp
...
```

*IF* I build the EXE with a single architecture (`armv7`) as above, then running the executable results in "Bad CPU Type In Executable." `file` tells me its a Mach-O but not Universal:

```
$ file cryptest.exe
cryptest.exe: Mach-O executable arm
```

*IF* I build for multiple architectures (`armv7` and `armv7s`), then the program runs as expected.

*IF* I build for multiple architectures (`armv7` and `armv7s`) and strip an architecture, then the program runs as expected:

```
$ mv cryptest.exe cryptest.exe.bu
$ xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo cryptest.exe.bu -remove armv7s -output cryptest.exe
$ codesign -fs "Jeffrey Walton" cryptest.exe
cryptest.exe: replacing existing signature
$ file cryptest.exe.bu
cryptest.exe.bu: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
cryptest.exe.bu (for architecture armv7):   Mach-O executable arm
cryptest.exe.bu (for architecture armv7s):  Mach-O executable arm
$ file cryptest.exe
cryptest.exe: Mach-O universal binary with 1 architecture
cryptest.exe (for architecture armv7):  Mach-O executable arm
```

Is it possible to instruct Apple's command line tools to build a binary with the extra universal headers even though its only single arch (to save the extra work of removing the unused architecture)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find a switch to build the universal binary; and I was not able to track down the Xcode magic that Apple is performing. I did find you could build a non-universal binary (single architecture) and then run `lipo` to create the universal.

```
$ make cryptest.exe
clang++ -o cryptest.exe -DNDEBUG -g -Os -pipe -fPIC -arch armv7
  --sysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
  -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM=1
  bench.o bench2.o test.o validat1.o validat2.o validat3.o adhoc.o datatest.o regtest.o fipsalgt.o dlltest.o ./libcryptopp.a  
$ lipo -info cryptest.exe
Non-fat file: cryptest.exe is architecture: armv7
$ lipo cryptest.exe -create -output cryptest.exe
$ lipo -info cryptest.exe
Architectures in the fat file: cryptest.exe are: armv7
```